# Install from backport with apt fail

Tags: apt, aptitude, dpkg

So little question, I've got this:

```
redis-server:
  Installed: 2:1.2.6-1
  Candidate: 2:1.2.6-1
  Version table:
     2:2.4.15-1~bpo60+2 0
        100 http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports/ squeeze-backports/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2:1.2.6-1 0
        500 http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

When I try to upgrade to newest version I get:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -t squeeze-backports redis-server
redis-server is already the newest version.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use:

```
sudo apt-get -q -y -t squeeze-backports -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install redis-server
```